mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1x400 and 784x10)
I'm following a tutorial on how to run a pytorch classification model but everytime I try to execute model_0(x_train.to(device) it always gives the same error.
import sklearn.datasets
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
NUM_SAMPLES = 1000
RANDOM_SEED = 42
x, y = make_moons(n_samples=NUM_SAMPLES,
                  noise=None,
                  random_state=RANDOM_SEED,
                  shuffle=True)
import torch



device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
device

import pandas as pd

data_df = pd.DataFrame({"x0" : x[:, 0],
                        "x1" : x[:, 1],
                        "y" : y})
data_df.head()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1])
x = torch.tensor(y, dtype=torch.float)
y = torch.tensor(y, dtype=torch.float)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,
                                                     y, 
                                                    test_size=0.6,
                                                      random_state=RANDOM_SEED)
len(x_train), len(x_test), len(y_train), len(y_test)

from torch import nn

class  MoonModelV0(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer_1 = nn.Linear(in_features=2, out_features=3)
        self.layer_2 = nn.Linear(in_features=5, out_features=1)

    def forward(self, x):

        return self.layer_2(self.layer_1(x))
    


model_0 = MoonModelV0().to(device)
model
# until now the code runs normal before I executed
model_0(x_train.to(device))

If there are some helpful suggestions I'll gladly take them.

sorry if the code is confusing

The code you shared doesn't give you exactly the same error as you've posted, but the error is caused by the fact that your input/weight matrices do not have the correct shape. You need to make sure that your input has the shape (n_observations, n_features), and the number of input features of your second layer needs to be equal to the number of output features of your first layer.
class  MoonModelV0(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer_1 = nn.Linear(in_features=1, out_features=3)
        self.layer_2 = nn.Linear(in_features=3, out_features=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layer_2(self.layer_1(x))

model_0 = MoonModelV0().to(device)
model_0(x_train.reshape(-1, 1).to(device))


i changed the in_features and the out_features but it's still gives the same error only this time instead of (1400 and 78410) it's now 1x400 and 1x3)

is there a mistake in the code or something if so let me know

Have you also added the reshape for your input? As mentioned your input should be of shape (n_observations, n_features).

i sort have added the reshape(-1, 1) but it doesn't work
